# TableB which usess column from TableA should update on updating tableA

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

I have two table t1 and t2. T2 uses two columns from t1 and everytime a new record is added to t1, t2 gets a record too. ID is a primary key in t1 and is used to check for duplicate records in t2. Now when my application updates a record on T1, how do I proceed to update t2. New to SQL and learning it myself. Please help me here.

Comment: Please provide example table schema, the SQL you are executing, the results, and the results you expect to receive.

Comment: The table 1 has column ID(primary key), name and Pay. Table2 has the three columns from table1 and also two more columns tax and net pay of its own. Now when I update table1 column I want to immediately update the corresponding row in table2 without creating a duplicate row. How do I achieve that